# Regex to find strings in iOS source code

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string

I need a regex to find string literals in iOS source code.
I want to collect them and then use in other place.

I need the regex to be able to parse next cases. Comments will be stripped beforehand:

```
char c = '"'; /* Not a string*/ NSString * *str1 = @"string"; // Here's a string
NSString *str2 = @"\"A\" class";
NSString *str3 = @"Long long"
                 @"long long string";
NSString *str4 = @"Another Long long"
                  "long long string";
NSString *str5 = @"Long untrimmed \
                   string";
```

I'm not very good with regex. I've tried this one:

```
@"(?<!')\"((\\\\\")*[^\"\\r\\n]*(\\\\\")*)*\"'{0}"
```

Unfortunately it hangs on such strings.

Comment: @vaichidrewar I added my regex that I use before, but it does not work with last two cases

Comment: how would you like to get the output of 3rd one? Should @ be in the output? Can the output be two different matches?

Comment: @vaichidrewar If @ will be in the output it still ok. I grab string and move it to another place, so if it will be compilable in another place, then it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with following regex `(^|[^'])(@?\"([^\"\\\\]|(\\\\.)|(\\\\\n)|(\"\\s*@?\"))*\")`, example:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(^|[^'])(@?\"([^\"\\\\]|(\\\\.)|(\\\\\n)|(\"\\s*@?\"))*\")" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:source options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [source length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@\n\n", [source substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]]);
}];
```

It works fine for any cases that I have in my mind plus it also works for `c-string`.

How it works:

- `(^|[^'])` Any character except `'` (because `'"'`) or beginning of line
- `@?\"([^\"\\\\]|(\\\\.)|(\\\\\n)|(\"(\\s*\\n*\\s*)*@?\"))*\"` starts with `@"` or `"` and ends with `"`.

  - Between can be any sequence of character except `"` or `\` (`[^\"\\\\]`)
  - it can be `\` char then skip next element too, it escaped anyway `(\\\\.)`
  - it can be escaped next line symbol (`\\\\\n`)
  - it can be multiline string, so we skip all whitespaces and new line symbols. Next line in string can be both from `"` and `@"` (`@?\"\\s*@?\"`)

Check online editor: http://regex101.com/r/gG0sF2

Answer (score 1):

Hello here is your solution  `"(\\.|[^"])*\"` use this regex to parse string literals in any text. you can check this regex on sample text on http://regexpal.com/
hope is helps !

Comment: @"(\\.|[^"])*\" try this its close enough. I was missing just '@'

Answer (score 0):

```
@(\".*\";|\".*\n.*\";|\".*\")
```

Check http://rubular.com/r/6dxtBzTE7P . I could not do 3rd one fully correct.

Comment: [NString stirngWithString:@"param"]; simple case

Comment: @Ossir Updated regexp and link

Comment: Nice one! Look like it catch all the cases. I mark it as correct as soon as I convert it to obj-c regex syntax and check it there

Comment: I just started to figure out how this regex works and look like it not so good. Why we have two same cases? `\".*\";` and `\".*\"`. Why \n can be only one time? String can take 2 (as in example) and more lines as well.